# How Can Set Dynamic Type <T> By Object Type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I want change My Entity Class With Object Type

```
MyEntity=x.GetType();

ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
ObjectSet<MyEntity> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<MyEntity>();
IEnumerable<string> keyNames = set.EntitySet.ElementType
                                            .KeyMembers
                                            .Select(k => k.Name);
```

change to

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
ObjectSet<x.GetType()> set = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<x.GetType()>();
IEnumerable<string> keyNames = set.EntitySet.ElementType
                                            .KeyMembers
                                            .Select(k => k.Name);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want change TEntity To My Object Type

Comment: You can't set a generic type parameter at runtime, it is a compile time thing. You can construct a generic type at runtime using reflection but its fiddly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `Reflection` you can invoke the `CreateObjectSet` method by the run-time type of `x`. Then you can extract the key names. Here is a extension method to do this:

```
public static class ObjectContextExtensions
{
    public static EntitySet GetEntitySet(this ObjectContext objectContext, object x)
    {
        //Get the approperiate overload of CreateObjectSet method
        var methodInfo = typeof(ObjectContext).GetMethods()
                         .Where(m => m.Name == "CreateObjectSet").First();

        //Supply the generic type of the method
        var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(x.GetType());

        //Invoke the method and get the ObjectSet<?> as an object          
        var set = genericMethodInfo.Invoke(objectContext, new object[] { });

        //Retrieve EntitySet of the set
        var prop = set.GetType().GetProperty("EntitySet");
        var entitySet = (EntitySet)prop.GetValue(set);
        return entitySet;
    }
}
```

now you can update your code as:

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
var set = objectContext.GetEntitySet(x);
var keyNames =  set.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name);
```

**EDIT:** A simpler version would be:

```
public static class ObjectContextExtensions
{
    public static EntitySet GetEntitySet<T>(this ObjectContext objectContext, T x)
    {
        return objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }
}
```